# Scada-LTS problem using Enhanced Image Chart

Tags: scadalts

I installed the scada-lts 2.6.18 version with Mysql 5.7 on Windows installed on AWS and everything is ok.

I created a "Graphical-View" with an "Enhanced image Chart" component that works fine when I access it locally, ie the browser installed on AWS windows.

When accessing remotely I get the following error:  "Expected property name or '}' in JSON at position 1"

Do you have any idea what this error could be?

I've tried checking Tomcat settings but haven't found anything that justifies running in the local
environment and not running on the internet.